# how to run custom wordpress hook action from plugin inside a theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes, hook

I'm trying to write a functionality plugin for a WordPress theme. Now I'm stuck on how to run my custom hook in any place in my theme.
This code is in my plugins file:

```
add_action( 'my_custom_hook_name', 'navi_h');

function navi_h(){
    echo "Hello world!"; //just for demo
}
```

In my themes function.php I have the following:

```
function my_navi() {
        do_action('my_custom_hook_name');
}
```

In my themes header I have the following:

```
my_navi();
```

Am I missing some information for you?

Comment: Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615118/wordpress-accessing-a-plugins-function-from-a-theme?rq=1 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111608/custom-hooks-in-wordpress-across-plugins?rq=1

Comment: No this didn't help me out! I read those before ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap do_action function inside other function. You just need to add the do_action function inside your theme where you want to appear.